# Can SwipeGesture (Present Modely/Show/Show Details/Deprecated Push) can only handle a maximum of 4 View controllers?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, navigation, uiswipegesturerecognizer

In my App I am using 5 `ViewControllers`. While I try to navigate to last one , It won't display. No error message displayed.

To go to next screen We are giving action to left swipe gesture using segue.

We have tried the solution provided in below link. They said to use push deprecated and then compile. Again use show `segue`(not specified Show / Show Details) we tried using both and the compile. It will solve the problem as it is issue with `Xcode`. But this solution doesn't work. I also not able to comment on their post.

[Can UINavigationController only handle a maximum of 4 Viewcontrollers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36251771/can-uinavigationcontroller-only-handle-a-maximum-of-4-viewcontrollers)

We have tried all navigation using segue **Show, Show Details,Present Modally and

Push Deprecated.**
In all segue except Push Deprecated controller neither go to fifth controller neither it give error. **Push** deprecated gives `sigbart` error while tried to run on iPhone.

We are using `Xcode10` and `iOS 12.0`.

While developing same app in `Xcode 9`  `Objective C` code we have first 2 navigation  are present modally, next two are having show segue and last one is present modally. It works fine on that code. We tried this solution also but it wont work. Currently I am upgrading same code in Swift with latest library and i am facing this issue. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit in number of pushed view controllers. Maybe it would be easier to add gesture recognizer in code on `viewDidLoad` for instance and put some breakpoints to see what goes on there.

To play around with these things you can try this minimalistic code which will push  a new view controller on every tap. You can create a new project and simply overwrite the content of autogenerated `ViewController` and all should work:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        present(UINavigationController(rootViewController: MyViewController()), animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}


class MyViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onTap)))
        self.title = "View controller \(navigationController?.viewControllers.count ?? 0)"
    }

    @objc private func onTap() {
        navigationController?.pushViewController(MyViewController(), animated: true)
    }
}
```

To explain:

An instance of `ViewController` will be created as a root view controller in your main window which is part of project settings (which storyboard to use) and part of autogenerated storyboard named `main`.

We need to wait for view to appear of the first view controller before we can present our new navigation view controller. We presented with having a root view controller as our own subclass of view controller called `MyViewController`. This view controller is not in storyboard.

When an instance of `MyViewController` comes into hierarchy (using push or present) a `viewDidLoad` will be called which creates a tap gesture recognizer set to a method to push a new instance of `MyViewController`. We also set a title depending on the number of view controllers on navigation controller just to have more information.

As said this is a minimalistic code. But in general you would do something like:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.addGestureRecognizer({
        let swipeRecognizer = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(onSwipeLeft))
        swipeRecognizer.direction = .left
        return swipeRecognizer
    }())
}

@objc private func onSwipeLeft() {
    let controllerToBePushed = UIStoryboard(name: "my_storyboard_name", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "the_identifier_I_set_in_storyboard") as! WhateverTheTypeOfMyViewControllerIs
    navigationController?.pushViewController(controllerToBePushed, animated: true)
}
```